# Ruby Scope Iterator

Tags: ruby, scope

this example:

```
def test(name)
    names = %w(one two three four)
    names.each do |name|
        puts name
    end
    puts name
end


test 'zero'

#out
one
two
three
four
four  #this is correct? should be zero
```

is correct the output of this program?

thanks and sorry for my English

Comment: Which version of Ruby are you using? This was changed in 1.9.

Comment: ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux]

Comment: then you are getting expected output as per your Ruby version

Comment: thanks with ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [x86_64-linux]
works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is expected behavior in Ruby 1.8**, but from Ruby 1.9.x, blocks variables have scope local to the block.

In Ruby 1.8, the block-variable ends up changing the global **binding**, if present. That's why, it changes the value of `name` variable. 
As per, Ruby 1.9.x, the block-variable **never** changes it's container binding like this. Output:

> > test('zero')
>   one
>   two
>   three
>   four
>   zero

Consider this example:

```
x = 10
(1..10).each { |y| print x+y, " "}
#=> 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

Here, `x` is **not** the block variable inside the block, so it picks up the **binding** present outside and uses that value.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior is 'correct' depending on which version of Ruby you are using.

In 1.8 and earlier, a block parameter could overwrite a local variable of the same name in the same scope as the block (not the scope within the block), as you've shown in your example.

In 1.9, 2.0, and 2.1, this no longer happens, and your final line of output would be `zero`.

Interestingly, in 1.9 an above, you can also specify that variables within a block should be considered local variables, and they won't affect the surrounding context:

```
v = "my value"
(1..3).each do {|n; v| v = n; puts v }
# => 1
# => 2
# => 3
puts v #=> "my value"
```